# Angularjs ng-class styling

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I am new to Angualrjs and am trying to write an ng-class to style a page number once its selected but it's not applying my style.

```
<a data-ng-repeat="p in pages track by $index" 
   data-ng-click="selectedPage(p)" href="#" 
   data-ng-class="{selectedPage: p == selectedPage}">
   {{p}}
</a>
```

style.css:

```
.selectedPage {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: I believe you don't want the "data-" in front of your styles. Try it without that and see if it works

Comment: Does your `$scope.selectedPage` stricly equals `p` when you debug?

Comment: Doesn't work unfortunately

Comment: @drew_w why not? it doesn't affect anything. it makes it compliant with html standards. http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: it seems you refer to `selectedPage` both as a function **and** as a property. you must be overriding it's definition in the controller. please post the controller source code.

Comment: @EduardGamonal Believe it or not - I wasn't aware that angular stripped the "data-" or "x-" from the beginning of the directive. A few google searches didn't reveal anything for "data-ng-model" so I assumed that just using "ng-model" might be something quick to try. As they say - live and learn!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this piece:

```
<a data-ng-repeat="p in pages track by $index" data-ng-click="selectedPage(p)" href="#" data-ng-class="{selectedPage: true}">{{p == selectedPage}}</a>
```

This way you can test quickly if the class gets applied in a simplest case of true. also you see what is the result of comparison that you are interested in.

From here if it works then it is a
problem wit logic statement.
If it is still not working then
make sure the class is not applied. Maybe it is discarded because of specifity rules in CSS? Take a peek in chrome dev tools at that to really be sure.
Apply class directly. I.e `class='selectedPage'` to see if it works.

Report back if you still can not figure it out.